# Installing Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 on identical hardware

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012-r2

We have to setup several small communications server with Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 - they will run a firewall along with several other applications. This is the model:

- http://www.supermicro.com/products/system/1U/5018/SYS-5018A-FTN4.cfm

The Microsoft doc says the free verson (i.e. Hyper-V Server 2012 R2) is pre-activated. Does that mean we could just clone the disk image from the first install for the additional installs? Obviously we need to adjust IP addresses and name (a pair will be backing each other up).

I've searched and search for a clue on this. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you - Richard

Answer (score 0):

You could clone it if you wanted to - HyperV server is free, you shouldnt run into any licensing issues.

But if you only have to do a few it is probably just as easy to install from a DVD.  And if you are seting up a lot of servers, it would be easier to automate the install and boot the setup over the network.

Comment: Thank you much. We don't really have that many to do at this point. But it sure took a lot of iterations of the Windows Update/reboots cycle to finally get all the updates applied to the first one. I was hoping to:

a. Speed up the second server setup.
b. Be sure it was setup identically.
I've seen bits an pieces of how to automate the install in the MS doc. If you have a concise reference on, for a simple case, how to automate the install that would be appreciated.

Thank you again - Richard